Shortcut for upper context menu panel
Can the upper panel of the context menu be mapped to a hotkey?
I find the upper panel of the two much more useful for quick edits. However, I just cannot remember all the 20+ hotkeys I'd need to replace this, as I do not use Word (2021) that often.
Coming from a background in programming I'm pretty used to just "leave" my mouse unless absolutely necessary and it would be awesome if that upper panel could also be pulled up via a hotkey like the lower one can.


I know of no commands or vba that accesses this. You could create a custom Ribbon tab with these commands and access that through the Alt-key.
